# How to pass a parameter to controller through view?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to pass an ICollection argument through a view to the TeamMemberController.
I use SQL database with ASP.NET Core
The database is stored locally. When clicking the red marked button there should appear a new page containing a list of the team members. The TeamMembers are currently displayed to the left of the marked button. The view button should send the parameter and direct us to the [teamMemberpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeZxe.png)
But as you can see, the list appears to be [empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF5Sp.png)

I have tried looking at the network in my [browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQtR5.png) and it gives me this:

**Query String Parameters(1)** :teamMembers: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BugTracking.Data.Entities.TeamMember]

**Video demonstrating issue**
https://youtu.be/dJbloxDCeok

**Code:**

**Project Index View**

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
   <a asp-action="ShowTeamMembers" 
   asp-controller="TeamMember" 
   asp-route-teamMembers="@item.TeamMembers" class="btn btn- 
   secondary">view</a>
 }
```

**TeamMemberController**

```
public class TeamMemberController : Controller
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _context;

    public TeamMemberController(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: TeamMembers
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.TeamMembers.ToListAsync());
    }

    public IActionResult ShowTeamMembers(ICollection<TeamMember> teamMembers)
    {
        return View(nameof(Index), teamMembers);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Your objects could be so big! Query string's has a limitation on how much data you can pass via those based on the browser. You should consider passing a unique id value (of the record) and using which get the entire record from db in your action method and pass that to the view.

Answer (score 0):

The anchor tag will generate a url link to the given Controller/Action. Thus, it can only contain parameters that can be contained in the url of the link. So you cannot pass an object through on the url.

Try passing the Id of the team member

**Project Index View**

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
   <a asp-action="ShowTeamMembers" 
   asp-controller="TeamMember" 
   asp-route-Id="@item.TeamMembers.ID" class="btn btn- 
   secondary">view</a>
 }
```

**TeamMemberController**

```
public IActionResult ShowTeamMembers(int Id)
{
    var team = _context.TeamMembers.Where(team => team.ID == Id).FirstOrDefault()
    return View(nameof(Index), team);
}
```

Comment: The TeamMembers is list of type List<TeamMembers>. This list does not contain an ID but the membes within the list does. Is there anyway to retrieve them and send them instead? I tried something like ``` asp-route Id="@item.TeamMembers.ForEach(member => member.Id)"````
But without any luck

Comment: Can you share your model or database structure?@Mahmood Seoud

Comment: So this is One to Many Relationship. Yes share model and db structure as @Chen asked. It will be helpful

Comment: I have solved the issue. Will be posting the solution very soon!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by sending the id of the project itself, instead of trying to send the List.
I could then from the TeamMemberController handle that object and take bind the list to a variable.

**Code:**

**Project Index View**

```
<a asp-action="ShowTeamMembers" 
asp-controller="TeamMember" 
asp-route-Id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-secondary">view</a>
```

**TeamMemberController**

```
   public IActionResult ShowTeamMembers(Guid Id)
    {
        Project? project = _context.Projects.Include(p => p.TeamMembers).Where(p => p.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();

        List<TeamMember> team = project?.TeamMembers ?? new();

        return View(nameof(Index), team);
    }
```